# YouTube JavaScript Player API seekTo() call

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I'm using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9j7R/5/)  in order to loads multiple videos using YT Iframe. but some of my videos i'd like to start them from a specific time, i know that i should use the seekTo() call (maybe somewhere in this code)

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");            //1
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){                         //2
    if(!/#ytplayer/.test(a[i].href)) continue;         //3
    var link = a[i].innerHTML.match(/\/vi\/([^\/]+)/); //4
    if(link) (function(vidId){                         //5
        a[i].onclick = function(){                     //6
            player.loadVideoById(vidId);               //7
        }                                              //8
    })(link[1]);                                       //9
}
```

if someone can help on this i'll appreciate it! because i don't know how to integrate it in this code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9j7R/5/) !!

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of [`loadVideoById`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#loadVideoById) function is:

```
// Argument Syntax
player.loadVideoById(videoId:String, startSeconds:Number, suggestedQuality:String):Void
// Object syntax
player.loadVideoById({videoId:String, startSeconds:Number, endSeconds:Number, suggestedQuality:String}):Void
```

It says here that:

> The optional startSeconds parameter accepts a float/integer. If it is
>   specified, then the video will start from the closest keyframe to the
>   specified time.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a small change to the fiddle code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/_Pez/yFFTU/) to set a start time for the videos:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        if(!/#ytplayer/.test(a[i].href)) continue;
        var link = a[i].innerHTML.match(/\/vi\/([^\/]+)/);
        var secs = a[i].href.match(/[^\?]*$/);
        if(link) (function(vidId,secs){
            a[i].onclick = function(){
                player.loadVideoById({'videoId': vidId, 'startSeconds': secs});
            }
        })(link[1],secs);
    }
}
```

This would enable you to make a video start playing 10 seconds in by giving it an href of "#ytplayer?10"

_Pez